# hibernate @ManyToOne no table relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, querydsl

Currently Using:

- Hibernate 4.0.1.Final
- Spring-data-jpa: 1.0.3.RELEASE
- QueryDSL: 2.3.0
- MySQL 5.x

I have an interesting problem that I have not found the answer, or clue for yet.  I have two tables that did not have foreign key or other relationship. But to try and solve this issue I added one. I want my User entity to hold it's UserRole.  This pattern is repeated throughout the database, but this is the easiest to describe.
Here are my tables:

**User**

```
userId           bigint(20) PK
password         varchar(255)
status           int(11)
userName         varchar(255)
userRoleId       long


CONSTRAINT `FK_USERROLE` FOREIGN KEY (`userRoleId`) REFERENCES `UserRole` (`userRoleId`)
```

**UserRole**

```
userRoleId       bigint(20) PK
userRoleDescription varchar(255)
userRoleDescriptionShort varchar(255)
```

Here are my classes:
**User.java**

```
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;
private String password;
private int status;
private String userName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userRoleId")
private UserRole userRole;
public UserRole getUserRole() {
    return userRole;
}

public void setUserRole(UserRole userRole) {
    this.userRole = userRole;
}
```

**UserRole.java**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "userRole")
public class UserRole {
private Long userRoleId;
private String userRoleDescription;
private String userRoleDescriptionShort;

@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
private List<User> users;

public UserRole() {...}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getUserRoleId() {...    }

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
public List<User> getUsers() {...}
```

So you can see where I am trying to associate the UserRole.userRoleId with the User.  I thought perhaps Hibernate would build the mapping and retrieve/associate the UserRole whenever the User was updated.

I have gone back and edited this post to use a foreign key between the tables, but on app server startup I get this:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: UserRole, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:304)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:288)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:216)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:467)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:268)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1287)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1729)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
```

I looked for that error, which appears related to JPA and transient variables, which is not the case here.

Comment: What's the userRole column of type long in the User table? What is it supposed to contain? Why don't you ditch it and replace it with a foreign key to UserRole.userRoleId, since this is what you want?

Comment: I put the long value for userRoleId thinking that Hibernate would associate them with that value.  When I used Hibernate to create the database, it made the User.userRole be of type blob and then error out that the column was too small.

Comment: It should have the same type as the userRoleId in the target table then, since it's supposed to hold the same thing.

Comment: edited to use foreign key in database.

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i would first clean the annotations, it is forbidden to annotate BOTH getter AND fields in the same entity, it could end up in unexpected results ...

```
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
private List<User> users;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
public List<User> getUsers() {...}
```

should be simplified in :

```
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
public List<User> getUsers() {...}
```